# WPF MVVM - Correct way to consume a web service asynchronously

Tags: wpf, mvvm, web-services

I have implemented MVVM in my WPF application. I was wondering what is the correct way to consume a Web Service from WPF MVVM app.

So far, I have created a DataAccess interface and a class that implements this interface. This would serve as a facade / proxy to the web service. The ViewModel gets a reference to this class as the constructor parameter so it can make any calls to get/set data, in this case it will be a Web service call. I would appreciate if you can guide me with some hints and / or direct me to some online resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know about 3 different ways of writting asynchronous code for MVVM:

- [the classical using callbacks](http://mark.mymonster.nl/2008/07/12/silverlight-threading-getting-back-to-the-ui-thread/)
- using coroutines:

  - [project Caliburn](http://caliburn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=IResult&referringTitle=Home&ProjectName=caliburn)
  - [Using C# 2.0 iterators to simplify writing asynchronous code](http://blogs.msdn.com/michen/archive/2006/03/30/564671.aspx)
  - [many more..](http://www.google.com/search?q=asynchronous+iterators)
- using Rx "Reactive Extensions" (this the newest):

  - [The Joy of Rx: Building an Asynchronous API with Rx and IQueryable](http://themechanicalbride.blogspot.com/2009/08/joy-of-rx-building-asynchronous-service.html)
  - [Using Reactive Extensions in Silverlight](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Using-Reactive-Extensions-in-Silverlight.aspx)

We aware that except the "classical" solution all the others use advanced techniques.

Comment: We typically use the callback approach, using a callback helper object, that is has a standard way of handling standard Web service exceptions.

Comment: Danice
I am currently using a callback approach. Thank you for the details. I'll have a look at all the approaches including the the classical callback approach you mentioned.

Agies, Thank you for letting us know the reason why you use the callback approach.